# terraform creating an Amazon S3 bucket by copying settings from another bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Is is possible to copy the settings from an existing bucket to create a new s3 bucket? I dont mean copy the contents of another Amazon S3 bucket. I want to copy the configuration settings - KMS key, IAM role, etc...

Comment: There isn't a "copy" settings API, but you can fetch the settings and the use them to create another one using awscli or the SDK in your preferred language.

Comment: how do i fetch the policy?